# PayPal IPN sends duplicate email receipts when making payment

Tags: php, email, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am going crazy trying to figure out what is happening; hoping somebody can shed some light.

I am using a PayPal button to test a membership renewal process. I have the account set up to use both PayPal PDT and PayPal IPN, and I am using a script to process both.

The script checks for the existence of `$_GET['paypal_ipn']` and processes as IPN if found; otherwise it processes as PDT.

I thought at first this was the source of my problem, which is:

**Each time I make a payment, I get exactly two email receipts from PayPal.**

However, I get both emails even if I don't click "return to site" and I'm still on PayPal's "completed" page. If I wait until the two email receipts are delivered, continuing back to my site does not result in a third email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The emails have identical receipt #s, but look slightly different:

**Receipt 1:**
[image: Receipt 1 - comes first]

**Receipt 2:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Well, two. But that is a good idea. I've been testing in FF/Mac (35.0.1) and Chrome/Mac (29...). We did see this error previously on a Windows machine. I forget what browser she was using.

Comment: I am seeing this consistently across browsers.

Comment: PDT and IPN do not trigger any processing on PayPal's end. They are onlt to inform you, not part of the processing stream. Since the receipt # is the same it's definitely just the one payment; frankly this looks like a PayPal bug. I would contact PayPal Customer Support directly. [PayPal has many varieties of post-transaction email, and the logic which selects one to send you would absolutely be subject to bugs like this, where due to coding error it might decide to send you two different versions...]

Comment: **"PDT and IPN do not trigger any processing on PayPal's end."** —that sounds like the key statement! I'm going to contact them. Could you please make your comment an answer? I will follow through w/ PayPal and then accept if you're right... thank you!

Comment: Any fixes yet? I'm having the same problem when my clients, currently hosting more than 20 clients on a single server, only Paypal giving me this issue...

Comment: @PizzaBoy we did not find a fix. Our members are getting duplicate emails. Since this is for an annual membership of limited scope, we did not pursue further. I'd check w/ PayPal...